# Algorithm for looping three Buttons in a TableRow

Tags: java, android, loops, android-button

`int numberofbutton=x;` will be provided.

I tried to loop but I failed because `numberofbutton` has to be divisible by 3. I can't write algorithm.

Based on `numberofbutton`, we have to loop three buttons in a TableRow programmatically.
I mean, if numberofbutton is **4**,

```
TableRow[0]->Button Button Button
TableRow[1]->Button
```

If it's **3**,

```
TableRow[0]->Button Button Button
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on ZouZou's answer, code is below but unsolved because tr[] is undefined:

```
int bn = 9;
        if (bn % 3 == 0) {
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[bn / 3];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3); i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        } else {
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[(bn / 3) + 1];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3) + 1; i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        }
        Button[] b=new Button[bn];
        for(int i=1;i<=bn;i++){
            b[i]=new Button(this);
        }
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bn; i++) {
            if(i%3==0){
                index+=1;
                tr[index].addView(b[i]);
            }else{
                tr[index].addView(b[i]);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**:

Full code but why doesn't it work?:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TableLayout tL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        int bn = 9;

        TableRow[] tr = null;

        if (bn % 3 == 0) {
            tr = new TableRow[bn / 3];
            for (int i = 1; i <= (bn / 3); i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        } else {
            tr = new TableRow[(bn / 3) + 1];
            for (int i = 1; i <= (bn / 3) + 1; i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        }

        Button[] b=new Button[bn];

        for(int i=1;i<=bn;i++){
            b[i]=new Button(this);
        }

        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < bn; i++) {
            if(i%3==0){
                index+=1;
                tr[index].addView(b[i]);
                tL.addView(tr[index]);
            }else{
                tr[index].addView(b[i]);
            }

        }

    }
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" >
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wow !! wtf?? -1 on this question. no one can provide full example yet. the person -1 must solve this question. or he/she may be a fool, doing -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo to perform such operations :

```
int index = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons; i++){
        if(i%3 == 0) {
          index += 1;
          tableRow[index] <- add Button here //here it's a new row we update the index
        }
        else
          tableRow[index] <- add Button here //we can add button to the current index
                                             //because there are less than 3 buttons
}
```

EDIT :

Replace :

```
int bn = 9;
        if (bn % 3 == 0) {
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[bn / 3];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3); i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        } else {
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[(bn / 3) + 1];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3) + 1; i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        }
```

By :

```
int bn = 9;
TableRow[] tr = null;
        if (bn % 3 == 0) {
            tr = new TableRow[bn / 3];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3); i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        } else {
            tr = new TableRow[(bn / 3) + 1];
            for (int i = 1; i <=(bn / 3) + 1; i++) {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: when adding buttons, which array value? i mean button[index] or button[i]?

Comment: Are you adding new Button each time or existing buttons ?

Comment: please see my question updated. can't solve about declaring TableRow[].

Comment: You have to declare `TableRow[] tr` out of your if statement. @RedHat_Father See my update